# accessing JSON data handle bars

Tags: json, handlebars.js

i get is this object on my view :

```
[
    {
        "2016": [
            {
                "model": "R8",
                "variant": "R8 s TRONIC"
            }
        ],
        "2017": [
            {
                "model": "A5",
                "variant": "A5 SPORTBACK"
            }]
```

}
    ]

this is in my object `pageContent`
i want to access only the name of the field i i want to get only the 2016, 2017

i tried to use this

```
{{#each pageContent as |item| }}

{{item}}

{{/each}}
```

i found a way to do this but i have many item not only the .0

```
{{#each pageContent as |item| }}

{{item.2017.0.model}}

{{/each}}
```

thats how i push it:

```
if (item.RegYear in result[0]) {

                    result[0][item.RegYear].push({
                        model: item.Model,
                        variant: item.Variant
                    });


                }
```

so i want to know how i access the name of the field , model and variant i have

Comment: Your JSON format is not valid, first array of object is not having the `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the solution finally :

```
{{#each pageContent as |item|}}
<pre>

    {{#each item as |obj|}}
        {{#unless  @last}}
            {{@key}}
                {{#each obj}}
                    {{this.variant}}
                {{/each}}
        {{/unless}}
    {{/each}}

</pre>

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get key from your object like this,

```
{{#each pageContent}} 
    {{@key}}: {{this}} 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: but how i can access them i get 0: [object Object]